# Exporting annotations using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, export, annotation

I am using ArcMap.

I have created a label with yellow text and a blue background. When exporting the whole map composition to PDF, the blue background of the labels doesn't appear. I've tried many exporting options but I haven't found a successful one. Then I've tried the 'Microsoft print to PDF' option (File>>Print) and it works.

Unfortunately, when I convert labels to annotations and try the 'Microsoft print to PDF' option, the labels appear with a striped pattern, as seen in the following image (In this case, exporting to PDF doesn't work either):

[image]

Is there a way to export these annotations with a good visual result?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: I had a problem exporting to PDF format. But I successfully exported files with doPDF programm. You can install it  https://www.dopdf.com/  and then try to print with doPDF (File>>Print)  as you did with the 'Microsoft print to PDF' option before.